# Remote acces to mySQL with facebook

Tags: mysql, facebook

I'm working in a Facebook app and I want to access a mySQL database. I have installed xampp because it has php, apache, mysql and others. I need access to mySQL database from the app I've been looking how to access in remote mode but I dond't found the solution.

The general method to acces to mySQL database from php is with this:
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
I have been configured a data base without pass and it accept any user name but I don't know what to put in the first, one ip, a general ip? How I know what is my server ip?
If I do a simple program in localhost with this it works good, but if I do the same in the app I have this problem: error connecting to the database

In my search of the solution I found that I have to modify "my.ini" form mySQL like this:
#bind-address="127.0.0.1" or bind-address = "0.0.0.0" but I have the same problem.

If it helps, I'm work also with heroku and git bash.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebookhttps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of the mysql_connect function, you can just put in the domain name for your server, e.g. `mysql_connect( 'mysqlserver.com', 'user', 'pass' );` and that should work (if you have a domain name for it, that is).

Using the `ipconfig` command on your server will give you it's IP address. You don't need to change any of the MySQL settings except allowing remote access to your Database.

Comment: Finaly my problem was that I have to modify the NAT table in my router and add MySQL. Thanks